# I'm getting a 404 error, don't know what I'm missing

Tags: servlets, http-status-code-404

I have the below servlet:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class MailServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        String m = request.getParameter("mail");
        String sub = request.getParameter("subject");
        String messg = request.getParameter("message");

        SendMail.send(m, sub, messg);
        out.print("Your Mail has been sent successfully");
        out.close();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to invoke it by below form:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body bgcolor="pink">
    <form action="MailServlet">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>To:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="mail"/><br/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Subject:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="subject"><br/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Message Text:</td>
                <td><textarea rows="12" cols="80" name="message"></textarea><br/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Send"></td>
                <td><input type="reset" value="Reset"></td>
            </tr> 
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

However, it returns a HTTP Status 404:

[image]

Comment: Did you map your servlet in web.xml?

Comment: No. can you please guide me on that? @BackSlash

Comment: look at http://www.studytonight.com/servlet/Sending-email-using-servlet.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Servlets need to be mapped in order to be able access them.

If you are using Servlet 3.0, you can use:

```
@WebServlet("/MailServlet") // /MailServlet is the partial URL of the servlet.
public class MailServlet extends HttpServlet {

    [...]

}
```

If you are not using Servlet 3.0, you have to map the servlet in `web.xml`, by putting these lines inside the `webapp` element:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MailServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.yourpackage.MailServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MailServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/MailServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

[Creating and configuring servlets](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/webapp/configureservlet.html)

Comment: Thanks for saving my time. It works.